# Unable to enumerate databases on SQL Server from PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I wish to check content of one database on server where I'm able to log into by means of Windows Authentication. Sounds really simple and many examples are provided over the Internet.

I tried few examples and each fails on my machine. I suspect, that there might be problem during credentials conversion.

My code (shortened) is as follows:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")

$User=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$credentials = Get-Credential $saUser | Select-Object *
$Pwd = $credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString 

$targetConn = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection') ('myServer', $User, $Pwd)
$targetServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $targetConn
```

till now there's no error message.

When I type `$targetServer`, I don't see any objects listed (no Databases as well).

When I tried to check `$targetServer.Databases`, I received:

> The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Failed to connect to server mmyServer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ConvertFrom-SecureString** converts a secure string into an "encrypted standard string" (a hash, which is intended to store the encrypted string in text format). So, you're providing a password hash (**$Pwd**) as the password argument when creating the **$targetConn** object, which is invalid.

You can get the plaintext password from the PSCredential object **$credentials** this way:

```powershell
$Pwd = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

However, according to [the documentation for the contructors for the **ServerConnection** class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ServerConnection.aspx), you can also provide a secure string as the password argument. So it should work if you simply leave out the `| ConvertFrom-SecureString`, i.e.

```powershell
$Pwd = $credentials.Password
```

That's probably a better idea, since it's a little more secure. If you use the first method to get the plaintext password, there's a possibility that the RAM location that stores the **$Pwd** variable will be paged out while the script is running, resulting in the plaintext password being written to the disk.